# How to force a rebind in WinRT as it is possible in WPF?

Tags: c#, mvvm, user-controls, windows-runtime, prism

I have a WinRT project based on prism with several pages, usercontrols etc.
For some reason I need to bind several views to a single model object accessed by the the viewmodels (each one belonging to a view).
The single model object is injected by a Unity container like other objects, that need to be singleton-like as the eventaggregator for instance.
To keep things simple I made an example with only one bool variable bound to a checkbox in each view, that should be synchronized over the views.
My problem is: When I check the box in the mainpage, the checkbox in a second page is following the value when navigating to that page(UserInpuPage in the example) BUT NOT the checkbox in the UserControl place on the Mainpage. 
After a debug session I saw the variables in the single model having the right values, but the GUI on the Usercontrol (MyUserControl in the example) is not updated. 
A Mechanism like GetBindingExpression(...) and then UpdateTarget() like in WPF seems not to exist in the WinRT library.
For design reasons (using prism mvvm I don't want to break the concept of the autowire and dynamical instantiation of the vm's) a static context defined in the resources section of the page and/or usercontrol is not what I'm looking for.

How can I achieve the update of the checkbox in the usercontrol with the model the same way as it works for the userinputpage after navigating?
Any help would be appreciated.

```
// Interface mendatory to work with Unitiy-Injection for RegisterInstance<ISingletonVM>(...)
public interface ISingletonVM
{
    bool TestChecked{ get; set; }
}

public class SingletonVM : BindableBase, ISingletonVM
{

    bool _testChecked = false;
    public bool TestChecked
    {
        get
        {
            return _testChecked;
        }

        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _testChecked, value);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the relevant code in the viewmodels (same for every vm, but vm from usercontrol in this case):

```
class MyUserControlViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private readonly ISingletonVM _singletonVM;

    public MyUserControlViewModel(ISingletonVM singletonVM)
    {
        _singletonVM = singletonVM;
    }

    public bool TestChecked
    {
        get
        {
            return _singletonVM.TestChecked;
        }

        set
        {
            _singletonVM.TestChecked = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Relevant XAML code fragments for the three views:

MainPage:

```
<prism:VisualStateAwarePage x:Name="pageRoot"  x:Class="HelloWorldWithContainer.Views.MainPage"...>
...    
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ctrl:MyUserControl ></ctrl:MyUserControl>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding TestChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </StackPanel>
 ...
```

UserInputPage:

```
<prism:VisualStateAwarePage x:Name="pageRoot"
                        x:Class="HelloWorldWithContainer.Views.UserInputPage" 
...
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding TestChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="440,190,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
...
```

UserControl:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="HelloWorldWithContainer.Views.MyUserControl" prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"    
<Grid>
    <CheckBox Content="CheckBox" IsChecked="{Binding TestChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="282"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user control never gets notified about changes in `MyUserControlViewModel.TestChecked` property and that's why the view is never updated. One thing you can do to fix this is to subscribe to your `SingletonVM.PropertyChanged` event in the constructor of `MyUserControlViewModel`. Your `ISingletonVM` needs to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. So the constructor of `MyUserControlViewModel` will be something like this:

```
public MyUserControlViewModel(ISingletonVM singletonVM)
{
     _singletonVM = singletonVM;
     _singletonVM.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) => OnPropertyChanged("TestChecked");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, adding the handler of the viewmodel to the singleton model did the trick.